# How can i drop out the words in a big dataframe with apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so this is what i am stumbling now..

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 'newshoe', 'b': 'pig eat', 'c': 'dim sum'},
                   {'a': 'good', 'b': 'happy', 'c': 'nice'},
                   {'a': 'extreme', 'b': 'perfect', 'c': 'jeans'}])


    a           b        c
0  new shoe  pig eat  dim sum
1  good       happy    nice
2  extreme   perfect   jeans
```

How could i do for dropping out the string like ['ea','ce'] by using the pd.apply()?
the following is what i expect:

```
    a           b        c
0  new shoe  pig t  dim sum
1  good       happy    ni
2  extreme   perfect   jns
```

The data is far bigger than i provide here though

sorry that i forgot i have more than a string which are needed to be replaced.. i update my question to be a list of strings to be replaceed instead of a simple string.

Comment: FYI,  you need quotes around your strings in your dataframe definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`df.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with regex param set to `True`

```
df.replace('ea', '', regex=True)

         a        b        c
0  newshoe    pig t  dim sum
1     good    happy     nice
2  extreme  perfect      jns
```

**EDIT:**

If you've a list of word to replace then use this

```
words = ['ea','ce']
pat = '|'.join(words)
df.replace(pat, '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

`DataFrame.apply` by default goes through the columns. So you can use:

```py
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('ea', ''))
```